# variadict template параметр из указателя c++

Tags: c++

Имеется шаблонный класс POSIX-потоков

```
template<class Res, class ...Args>
class MyPThread
{
  public:
  Res foo(Args... args){//...
  return Res(); 
               }
```

и имеется "первичная"-функция принимающая указатель (именно она и будет передана в pthread_create())

```
static void* bar(void* arg){
//call foo()
     }
};
```

как в функции bar() можно достать из указателя параметры и передать их в метод foo()?

Answer (score 2):

Например можно упаковать аргументы в кортеж, передать указатель на этот кортеж, а потом в функции `bar` вызвать `foo` передав этот кортеж посредством `std::apply`

```
static void * bar(void * const p_args) noexcept
{
    auto const & args{*static_cast< ::std::tuple< MyPThread *, Args... > * >(p_args)};
    auto res{::std::apply(&MyPThread::foo, args)};
    return nullptr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Я бы вот как сделал.

Делаете лямбду без параметров, которая захватывает все необходимое и вызывает нужную функцию:

```
auto lambda = [...]{...};
```

Сохраняете ее куда-нибудь, чтобы она не удалилась, пока поток работает.

Делаете еще одну лямбду, без списка захвата, которую будете передавать в `pthread_create`. Эту лямбду можно никуда не сохранять, после вызова `pthread_create` она не нужна.

```
auto invoker = [](void *ptr) -> void*
{
    auto &lambda_ref = *(decltype(lambda) *)ptr;
    lambda_ref();
    return nullptr;
};
```

Все, теперь в `pthread_create` в качетсве функции передаете лямбду `invoker`, а в качестве `void *arg` - адрес первой лямбды.

Домашнее задание - придумать, как прикрутить ко всему этому возвращение значения из потока.